# Raspberry Pi MIDI Looper

Tags: pi-3b+, midi

I would like to write a script that allows MIDI data to be recorded, then sent back out in a loop similar to how a drum machine works. Think drum machine without the audio data. Only MIDI data. I'm not a programmer, I'm a musician, so any help getting started is appreciated. KMIDImon is close to the kind of program I want, but it's not set up to be a looper. I am able to successfully send and receive MIDI data to/from the RPi3 however, so I think that's a good start.

Comment: `arecordmidi`/`aplaymidi`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try these and see how it works. I'll post back later.

Comment: @CL. I don't really know how those two pieces of software actually work. I did some research, and as far as I can tell, those are backend applications that allow other software to use MIDI via the ALSA stuff. I'm fine with a CLI application solution to my problem, but I'm pretty new to Linux, so I'm sure I don't know what I'm doing. In addition to some research, here is what I tried:
sudo apt-get install arecordmidi and also tried aplaymidi, but neither are packages I don't think since the RPi stated those packages couldn't be located. Any and ALL help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: After some more research, I'm convinced there HAS to be something out there that will do what I want. Every time I Google search anything with Loop and Raspberry Pi in it, I get a lot of results, but most relate to looping audio. Looping audio has GOT to be WAY more taxing on the Pi than simply recording MIDI data for the number of measures I want, then sending the MIDI data right back out again. It's a loop. I don't need a full-blown DAW or any DJ sampler. I only need to record the MIDI for, say, 16 measures, then whatever MIDI data was recorded in that time should then be looped.

Comment: These tools are part of the `alsa-utils` package. But for looping, you probably need to write some software yourself.

Comment: Thank you @CL. I have the packages I need for ALSA. I was hoping you wouldn't say that lol. This guy from four years ago has the right idea, and it's close to what I need: https://youtu.be/ZGNqPMBFaSY
Perhaps a few changes, and probably not Java, but on the right track.

Comment: After some more research, I found what I needed. Giada is the looper I was looking for. Now I have other questions that don't really belong under this thread. I'm going to mark this as answered...once I figure that out. Thanks again @CL.

Comment: You need to write an actual answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several applications that offer looping capability with the RPi. Most of them are geared toward looping audio rather than just MIDI data, but Giada does both. I am still working out the kinks with using Giada, but so far it seems to do what I want.